Minimum requirements of GCC towards a new target ISA
I'm porting the GCC and Binutils to a unique (really simple) 8-bit RISC soft processor.
I would like to be able to execute 16 and 32 bit arithmetics. The current ISA is probably not sufficient yet for a C compiler. Is there a set of requirements somewhere about the basic needs of the compiler in terms of the instructions that a new target should have? I suppose it probably needs push, pop, arithmetics with carry, shift, mov, logical etc and my question is what kind of instructions should I have of these?
I went through the documentation of the GNU GCC but I couldn't find an exact explanation of what are the basic requirements towards a new target ISA.

We see C compilers call (internal) library functions to do floating point, and even integer sizes beyond some natural ones (e.g. long long).  In fact, most operators and data type sizes can be supported by calling library functions.  Thus, I might say that all you really need is small, e.g. 8-bit arithmetic because we can generally make larger integer sizes by composing sequences, whether inline or by calling library functions.
Some mechanism by which to map C's variables to physical machine storage, including:

Global variables
Parameters
Local variables
Return values

You'll need some form of conditional and unconditional branching, for basic control flow.
For function calling you need to be able to create and pass a return address.  For return (i.e. use return address), switch construct, and call by function pointer, we need some kind of indirect branch via pointer — in a simple ISA these may all share the same hardware instructions, and other ISA's these may have dedicated instructions.
You'll need a stack to enable recursion.
Note that popular RISC processors like MIPS & RISC V do not have push & pop, but can simulate their effect with multiple instructions (though usually opt for something more efficient that singular push & pop).
